# Why are the trigonometric functions in Julia seem to be slower than in Numpy?

Tags: numpy, julia

I'm new to Julia, so may be doing something wrong.  But I ran a simple test of trigonometric functions, and Julia seems to be significantly slower than Numpy.  Need some help to see why.

--- Julia version:

```
x = rand(100000);
y = similar(x);
@time y.=sin.(x);
```

--- Numpy version:

```
import numpy
x = numpy.random.rand(100000)
y = numpy.zeros(x.shape)
%timeit y = numpy.sin(x)
```

The Julia version regularly gives 1.3 ~ 1.5 ms, but the Numpy version usually gives 0.9 ~ 1 ms.  The difference is quite significant.  Why is that?  Thanks.

Comment: Never benchmark in the global scope, and check if Julia isn't able to infer types.  These aren't really valid comparisons IMO, but it's been a while since I've looked at Julia.  Also isn't there a benchmark tool in Julia that would be better than using `time`?

Comment: You should expect Numpy and Julia to perform roughly the same for things like this. Try using BenchmarkTools and interpolate the variables. When I use `@btime $y .= sin.($x)` I get approximately 30% speedup over `@time y .= sin.(x)`. If I write out the loop and use multithreading with 4 threads, I get another 3.5x speedup with 10^5 elements.

Comment: Suprisingly, though, I see a much larger difference than you do, even after the improved benchmarking. Numpy appears to be 10x as fast as Julia on calculating `sin`(!) Very odd.

Comment: In my benchmarks Python seems to use multiple threads and this is probably the reason. The benefit of this is apparent only for large vectors. @DNF - can you please double check on your machine?

Comment: Could this be a Intel Math Library (libimf) vs OpenBLAS (libopenlibm) issue? I once compared `sinh` and found that libimf was about 40% faster than libopenlibm. My feeling is that this is unrelated to the issue here, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = rand(100000);
y = similar(x);
f(x,y) = (y.=sin.(x));
@time f(x,y)
@time f(x,y)
@time f(x,y)
```

Gives

```
julia> @time y.=sin.(x);
  0.123145 seconds (577.97 k allocations: 29.758 MiB, 5.70% gc time)

julia> @time y.=sin.(x);
  0.000515 seconds (6 allocations: 192 bytes)

julia> @time y.=sin.(x);
  0.000512 seconds (6 allocations: 192 bytes)
```

The first time you call a function, Julia compiles it. Broadcast expressions generate and use an anonymous function, so if you broadcast in the global scope it will compile it each time. Julia works best in function scopes.